# TypeError only appears when executed on Linux, works perfectly fine on Windows

Tags: python, sql, string, sqlite, networking

So I have this python file I created on windows:

```
import sqlite3
import getmac
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
prevAmount = 0

while True:
    nm.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/24', arguments='-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')
    hosts_list = nm.all_hosts()
    hosts_list.remove('192.168.1.1')
    print(hosts_list)
    if len(hosts_list) > prevAmount:
        for host in hosts_list:
            mac = getmac.get_mac_address(ip=host)
            connection = sqlite3.connect('OpenSesame.db')
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblDevices WHERE DeviceMAC ='" + mac + "');")
            bExists = cursor.fetchone()
            if bExists[0] == 1:
                cursor.execute("SELECT DeviceName FROM tblDevices WHERE DeviceMAC ='" + mac + "';")
                persoon = cursor.fetchone()
                print(persoon[0])
        prevAmount = len(hosts_list)
    elif len(hosts_list) < prevAmount:
        prevAmount = 0
```

I'm currently stuck trying to implement it on a Raspberry Pi, obviously running Linux.
The complete output I get is:

```
['192.168.1.17', '192.168.1.55', '192.168.1.56', '192.168.1.59', '192.168.1.70']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RelayOpenSesame.py", line 19, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblDevices WHERE DeviceMAC ='" + mac + "');")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

This ONLY happens on Linux, not on windows.
I've also noticed when connecting a device to the network that is in fact in the database, that it does print out the name, which is done by line 23: `print(persoon[0])`
So, the program runs through line 19 that causes the error, and probably only after the last line it throws the error stopping the program.

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Obviously at some point mac is None. What happens when you `print(mac)` immediately after you retrieve it? In the output you show there is only the host list printed and then error. No other output.

Comment: As per [the docs](https://github.com/GhostofGoes/getmac/blob/7a167c8bf31d2e4ef3c5d124fe2646d43a835f27/getmac/getmac.py#L136) `get_mac_address()` will return _`None` if one could not be found or there was an error_

Comment: don't get into the habit of string concattenating sql params - use parametrized queries! https://xkcd.com/327/ - [https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/little-bobby-tables-sql-injection-and-execute-as/](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/little-bobby-tables-sql-injection-and-execute-as/)

Comment: @buran THAT'S IT! I completely forgot about the fact that it retrieves the mac of every IP found. I was so focused on the error I didn't think logically. Adding `print(mac)` revealed that get_mac_address() works for every IP except the raspberry pi's IP, which ends with 70. As you can see I remove 192.168.1.1 which is the router, so I just also removed 192.168.1.70 which worked. Now I only wonder why this is? The raspberry pi is supposed to have a mac address right?

Comment: Note that the docs says 'local interface or remote host". So I **guess** there is some limitation of the package - I didn't go into details of the code. Try with interface name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it become clear from the comments - the problem is with host/local ip for which `getmac.get_mac_address()` returns `None`. I also confirmed that on Linux.
Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/GhostofGoes/getmac/issues/48) - it's known bug/limitation of the package - [it does not work for host ip on Linux](https://github.com/GhostofGoes/getmac/issues/48#issuecomment-522198912). Check the discussion for more info.
You can use local interface name though.